# JSON Parameter Missing

Tags: php, json, post

I'm facing an issue of calling a parameter in my JSON which it's weird because all the rest are called and present.

```
$.post( "http://localhost/mydir/corspage.php", { 
     data_key: itemKey[0],
     selected_id: itemKey[1],
     themeproduct: myTheme.getProduct(),
     themecategory: myTheme.getCategory(),
     themeid: myTheme.getthemeId(),
     themesize: myTheme.getsize(),
     themecover: myTheme.getcover(),
     themefinishing: myTheme.getfinishing(),

      } ).done(function( data ) {
```

and I do call them through get function which it does work for all of them, below is sample of the finishing and cover GET\SET functions:

```
this.setCover = function(cover){this.cover= cover;}
this.setFinishing= function(finishing){this.finishing=finishing;}
this.getcover=function()         {return this.cover;}
this.getfinishing=function()     {return this.finishing;}
```

But when I do fetch my POST using $_POST["themefinishing"] this results that is what I get:

```
    (
[data_key] => size
[selected_id] => 1
[themeproduct] => 1
[themecategory] => 1
[themeid] => 1
[themesize] => 1)
```

Any kind help or suggestions?